# laravel: how to install facebook SDK using composer

Tags: laravel-4, facebook-sdk-3.0

Friends, I am new in laravel. I don't know how to install Facebook SDK in laravel project.

Please tell me how to install the Facebook SDK in laravel project using composer.

Comment: http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/php/facebook-php-sdk-with-composer/

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
"require" : {
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "3.0.*"
}
```

to your composer.json file.
And then run composer install